# Lync Attendee meetings on ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, microsoft-lync

I need to join Microsoft Lync Attendee online meetings, mostly as a participant (not host).

Is there a way I can configure Lync Attendee, or preferably another open source client to do the same?

**NOTE: Although I do need Lync support and appreciate the help, the question here is about the Lync Attendee....their online audio/video conferencing client.**

Comment: I hope you find your answer ... but this doesnt bode well :( http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsplanningdeployment/thread/a0417c86-0b52-46f9-ba13-21b41b01a5b1

Comment: have you tried using wine to run it?

Comment: @MegaEverything : I am not a big fan of wine. Haven't tried it yet, but would try if there are no 'purer' methods available.

Comment: @charlie - apparently microsoft have joined skype to lync.  Video support is promised soon - so in theory skype linux will be able to access lync.  You may just have to wait a while! - http://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/05/30/microsoft_links_skype_to_lync/?utm_source=feedly

Comment: Skype is still a whole other thing than Skype for Business/Lync; the Linux Skype client from Microsoft doesn't (as of 2018) give access to Lync/Office Communicator accounts.

Answer (score 13):

Actually it is not possible to run the Lync client on Linux. The "lync Web app" client does not work on Linux even with the binaries of the mono project. For the time being Microsoft doesn't say if they have it on their road map.

There are third party Linux clients (including one that Microsoft qualified, the snom embedded client that does presence and enterprise voice). The protocol documentation makes it possible for the Linux community to build such clients. There is no Microsoft built full client, but the Microsoft OWA web client is supported on Linux and delivers IM and Presence.

You can try The [SIPE Project](http://sipe.sourceforge.net/install/), which is a third-party Pidgin plugin for Microsoft LCS/OCS.

> The SIPE project develops a third-party plugin for the Pidgin
>   multi-protocol instant messenger. It implements the extended version
>   of SIP/SIMPLE used by various products such as Microsoft Office
>   Communications Server, Reuters Messaging, Microsoft Live
>   Communications Server. With this plugin you should be able to replace
>   your Microsoft Office Communicator client with Pidgin.
>
> It is not recommended to compile the source code yourself. Experience
>   has shown that it is difficult to get all prerequisites correctly in
>   place, especially for new Linux users. Instead you should use the
>   ready-to-use installation packages which most OS distributions offer
>   under the name pidgin-sipe.

> The snom enterprise solution utilizes the comprehensive unified
>   communications functionality of our Unified Communications partners'
>   solutions to provide large scale enterprises and corporations with a
>   complete communications system: snom devices are compatible with both
>   of these partner’s unified communications solutions whilst remaining
>   as fully functional and interoperable devices in their own right.
>
> This means that not only can you take full advantage of all the rich
>   presence, video conferencing and communications management strengths
>   of unified communications, but you can also sleep easy in the
>   knowledge that if you decide to switch to a different enterprise level
>   solution in the future, you will not need to ditch the phones.

Also, it seems like Pidgin, is being mentioned a lot with regards to Lync.

> Pidgin is a chat program which lets you log in to accounts on multiple
>   chat networks simultaneously. This means that you can be chatting with
>   friends on MSN, talking to a friend on Google Talk, and sitting in a
>   Yahoo chat room all at the same time.
>
> Pidgin runs on Windows, Linux, and other UNIX operating systems.

Sources, and more information:

<sup>[SIPE](http://sipe.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

<sup>[SNOM](http://www.snom.com/en/solutions/snom-enterprise-solution/)</sup>

<sup>[Microsoft Lync Qualified Products](http://www.snom.com/en/products/unified-communications/microsoft-lync-qualified-products/)</sup>

<sup>[PR Web](http://www.prweb.com/releases/2013/3/prweb10484487.htm)</sup>

<sup>[Microsoft Lync on Linux](http://blog.dataforce.org.uk/2012/04/microsoft-lync-on-linux/)</sup>

Comment: ..thanks...I knew Microsoft wont be bothering with Linux support just yet. Could you please tell some more about the third party linux clients...esp the microsoft qualified one?

Comment: Although I do need Lync support and appreciate the help, the question here is about the Lync Attendee....their online audio/video conferencing client.

Comment: Install the [sipe](http://sipe.sourceforge.net/install/) plugin for Pidgin, chat functions work well.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible on Ubuntu 32 bit, Ubuntu 64 bit, SUSE, Red Hat, Cent OS

Look for [Lync On Linux](http://fisil.com/linuxlync.html).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This worked for me, without entering any advance proxy or any settings.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

This does seem to work now, using the sipe-collab ppa.  I've managed to connect to lync conferences, using pidgin running on Ubuntu 14.04LTS (with some personal modifications to get some 16.04 features), and it works.

see https://launchpad.net/~sipe-collab and https://launchpad.net/~sipe-collab/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

I use http://ppa.launchpad.net/sipe-collab/ppa/ubuntu trusty

I have:-

1. Application/Desktop sharing (both control given and in view only mode)
2. Audio, from the presentation

I believe I can send sound, but as I have no decent mic, apart from having to mute my mic to prevent static noise being sent to all other participants in a meeting, I've not tested that bit.

Join a Lync meeting using the Accounts/<account>/Join scheduled conference menu, then enter the link that was sent to you under the  link.

Comment: 18.04 seems to have almost-as-new versions as that ppa – anyone tried conference calls with the regular packages?

Comment: I've not had time to reinstall my office desktop since 18.04 came live.  I'll probably do that in January/February, so I'll let you know how I get on

Answer (score 1):

There is no Lync Attendee client developed specially for Ubuntu. In Ubuntu your only real option is the [**Lync Web App**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/communicator-help/welcome-to-microsoft-lync-web-app-HA101908015.aspx#_Toc271712150) (which is only meeting join, no IM/Presence, Conferencing or Voice). To use it you will need an alternative to Microsoft Silverlight. This is [Moonlight](http://www.go-mono.com/moonlight/download.aspx). Use the instructions from the link attached to install or follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/235588/147044).

Comment: Actually, I was not able to have the Lync Web App working in Firefox under 12.04. I haven't tried again with the newest Moonlight (3.99), though.

Comment: @charlie So, did you tried to use Lync Web App with Moonlight?

Answer (score 1):

One possible alternative that I use is to have a Windows VM (using Virtualbox) with Lync installed in it and run it in "Seamless" mode in Virtualbox so that the Lync window appears as a separate window on your Ubuntu desktop. Slightly complicated, but it's the best workaround I could find for your/our problem.